# Access Google Sign-In username globally

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter, google-signin

I have a problem with Firebase Auth in flutter, more specifically the `user.displayName` query. I use mandatory Google Sign In at the first screen of my app, so I can guarantee that on all subsequent screens the user has a name and a userId associated with him.

Every time I want to access the username however, all I do right now is essentially authenticate the user again with:

```
GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await googleSignIn.signInSilently();
GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
FirebaseUser user = await auth.signInWithGoogle(
  accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
  idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
);
futureId = user.uid;

print("signed in " + user.displayName);
return user.displayName;
```

which obviously takes up unnecessary time and bandwidth.

Is there another way of doing that, since the user has already signed in once before? Could I maybe access the userdata that gets stored by Firebase Auth for use in other Firebase products (like Firestore)?

Answer (score 3):

FirebaseAuth has an `async` method called `currentUser` that can be used to access the currently authenticated user.

dummy example:

```
class SomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SomePageState createState() => new _SomePageState();
}

class _SomePageState extends State<SomePage> {
  String _userName = "...";
  _getUserAuth(){
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user){
      setState((){this._userName= user.displayName;}); 
    });
    print(this._userName);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
      child: new FlatButton(
        child: new Text(this._userName),
        onPressed: _getUserAuth,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! While the code seem to be correct, for me the function still returns null as the current username. This should theoretically not be possible since I use Firestore in the same app that is configured to require authentication on read. Do you know what could be the problem here?

Comment: It is working just fine with me, maybe show me how are you wiring things up and I will try to help